# How can I remove this crease/fix the topology of this subdivided mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, subdivision-surface, topology

I am modeling a Z GT500 rear fender but I can't fix specific shading problems on it due to bad topology, one of them being this corner having an ugly crease with subdivision surface applied:
[image]

[image]

No matter how much I play with moving the vertices and using looptools Gstretch, I can't get it to disappear to be nice and smooth.

How could I make a nice topology to get rid of this crease please?

I'll include a .blend file if you want to take a closer look (It has bad topology on other parts too like the holes because I can't do topology properly but that's not the main issue as of now):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_yxzJYuf6iRqaJVv2cm0AECOZgF1iDxL/view?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this topology instead? You'll need to move some vertices, flatten some faces and shade smooth again:

[image]

Comment: I had this as the original topology but haven't tried flattening with looptools yet, now I gave it a shot and it looks much better than it originally was, thank you as always moonboots :)

Comment: The topology there is also very nice, did you make that yourself or did you remesh somehow? Is there any tutorial on how to make such topology please?

Comment: I did it myself, you need to use the knife, join some vertices, move some, etc, I've made some modeling tutorials but each object is different, but for this shape typically that's the topology that seems to work imho

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I just checked your YT channel :)

Comment: You're welcome........  ;)